# How do I create a migration that has two columns that reference the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 and PostGres 9.4.  I have two columns in my table that will both reference another table.  The other table is called "encrypted_fields".  I would like to name my columns "enc_field1_encrypted_field_id" and "enc_field2_encrypted_field_id".  I tried this migration

```
class MySecureInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :secure_accounts do |t|
      t.references :encrypted_field, :enc_field1_encrypted_field_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :encrypted_field, :enc_field2_encrypted_field_id, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

but it blows up with the below error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "enc_field1s" does not exist
```

How do I adjust my migration to avoid the error?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo (`encryptd_field`)? Might not be your problem, but jumped out.

Comment: Good call.  I corrected the typo but the error remains.

Comment: I don't see the point. The references type of column is used to link a model to another. There is no point in doing that twice. `enc_field1_encrypted_field_id` and `enc_field2_encrypted_field_id` will both hold the same key of the record from the other table `encrypted_field`. Can you develop a bit here

Comment: I have a table that will have two foreign keys to antoerh table.  They're not linking to the same data -- different rows.  Get it?

Comment: To me, secure_accounts is the parent of encrypted_field. Encrypted_field should be the model referencing to secure_accounts (not the other way round), and secure accounts having a has_many relationship and own has many encrypted_fields as you want. Please provide your models and constraints so we know better. The provided answer below may do the trick too..

Comment: What provided answer below are you tlaking about?  I see no such answer.

Comment: The owner has deleted it. I have not really checked it so cannot say if it would have worked.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in Rails 5 onwards:

```
class MySecureInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :secure_accounts do |t|
      t.references :enc_field1_encrypted_field, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :encrypted_fields }
      t.references :enc_field2_encrypted_field, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :encrypted_fields }
    end
  end
end
```